Unity - How to not detect self when using Physics.overlapSphere
I'm making a 3d Tower Defense game, and I have a 10x10 of tiles that the path will be on. I'm currently trying to make it so when you click, the game detects the tiles around it to prevent from illegal paths. However, it's detecting itself. How do I fix this?
Basically, I don't want each tile to detect itself. Code is listed below.
PathCreator.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.Android.Types;
using UnityEngine;

public class PathCreator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Mesh StraightPath;
    public Mesh TurnPath;
    public float radius = 5f;
    public static string targetTag = "StraightPath";
    public static bool Message = false;
    public static bool Message2 = false;
    public int pathLayer;
    public Collider myCollider;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pathLayer = 7 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Tile");
        myCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius, pathLayer);
        foreach (var hitCollider in hitColliders)
        {
            if (hitCollider != myCollider)
            {
                if (hitCollider.gameObject.CompareTag(targetTag))
                {

                    if (!Message2)
                    {
                        Message2 = true;
                        print("Found Me!");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Message)
                {
                    print("Found path!");
                    Message = true;
                }
            }
            }
        }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        print("click!");
        gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = StraightPath;
        gameObject.tag = "StraightPath";
        Message = false;
        Message2 = false;
    }
}

PathSelect.cs (unused currently)
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PathSelect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject StraightPath;
    public GameObject TurnPath;
    public Camera PathChooser;
    public Camera MainCamera;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        PathChooser.enabled = true;
        MainCamera.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

This is my current code, and I have those tiles. I can't put a layer on the tiles, since they ALL need to detect for when the path becomes a straight path (see second image)

I want to prevent ^^ That from happening.
How do I fix this?

I don't quite get what your actual goal is and what exactly is performing this sphere check .. is the PathCreator component one of these tiles that can be detected itself? Why? Does this mean each and every tile is making a sphere check each and every frame? That sounds rather inefficient

You realise it saying found me is it actually finding something else not itself right?

@derHugo What's the better solution? Essentially, I want to ensure that you can't have a path next to each other. (Player will create their own path)

You mean each player has their own tiles? Just use different layers then?

No, I mean I want the player to create their own tower defense path, but I don't want you to be able to have a path next to a path

You can skip the calling object from being processed, like this:
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, radius, pathLayer);
foreach (var hitCollider in hitColliders) {
    if (hitCollider.gameObject == gameObject)
        continue;

    // Continue processing stuff
}


Isn't this basically already what OP checks in if(hitCollider == myCollider) since myCollider = GetComponent<Collider>() on the same object as this ... yours is tbh more elegant and requires a GetComponent call less ... but the behavior should be exactly the same as OP already has - except OP has something actually happening in that case and you straight continue now

you're right, I didn't notice. Then I don't get what the purpose of the question is since OP is already skipping the calling object.

I'm trying to make it so it won't detect itself. Right now, it's detecting itself, and whatever else is in the sphere. (it should either say found me OR found path)

I think I might be able to have only the path tiles try to detect it based off of rotation, but essentially, I wanted to have the player make their own tower defense path but prevent player from having 2 paths next to each other for many obvious reasons
